# How to set wait while downloading PDF file using protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am downloading pdf file, but the file will take more than 2 minutes for downloading and I need to check/verify whether the file is downloaded or not. so I need to wait for 2 minutes and after that I need to perform verification, can anyone help me how to use browser.wait() method in such scenario.

```
 control.getText().browser.wait(120000).then(function(text) {
    var filename = downloadPath+'AmPMIC_' + text +'.pdf';
    console.log(filename);
      if (fs.existsSync(filename))
        {
        return deferred.resolve(true);
        } 
        else {
          return deferred.reject('verify failed');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const text = do get text here;
const filename = downloadPath+'AmPMIC_'+test+'.pdf';
return browser.wait(() => {
    return fs.existsSync(filename);
}, 30000, 'not downloaded').then(() => {
    console.log("File donwloaded");
});
```